# Скрыть виджеты в Kivy по аналогии с Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, kivy

Начал изучать Kivy сразу после Tkinter. Сначала все шло легко но потом я столкнулся с проблемой. Вопрос - как скрывать виджеты в Kivy? А именно не просто кнопки но и макеты (Layouts). В пример приведу pack_forget() и .pack() в tkinter.

Comment: Каждый виджет по отдельности скрыть или что вы хотите?

Comment: pack размещает виджет, зачем вы его в примере используете? Вам ведь нужно скрыть виджет!

Comment: Я имею ввиду что при использовании pack он сохраняет данные типо букв и цифр в строке ввода, а скрыть я хочу именно контейнер этих виджетов (кнопок и изображений). Контейнер это FloatLayout если что. Если нужно могу код кинуть.

Answer (score 1):

По аналоги с tkinter не получится так как в kivy не предусмотрено скрытие виджета.

Но есть несколько решений, такие как удалить виджет из родителя (потом снова его добавить), ещё можно уменьшить виджет до размера 0.

Comment: Если уменьшить виджет до 0 то он вообще не будет отображаться?

Comment: И еще если удалить виджет то он потеряет свои данные? Ну типо символы в строке ввода (как пример)

Comment: Да все данные потеряются, поэтому нужно сохранять состояние.

Comment: Если уменьшить размер до 0, то да по идее он исчезнет.